# How to show error message when the login details are invalid?

Tags: objective-c, json, button

I have created a textfield for username and another for password and a button. now in JSON post if i entered wrong details an error message has to be displayed for me. if i entered correct details it should go to another view controller.
How it can be done?

```
self.urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

self.serviceURLReq = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dokitatesting.com/API/doctorLogin"]];


self.serviceURLReq.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

[self.serviceURLReq setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


NSString * dataToServer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserName=%@&Password=%@",self.userNameField.text,self.passwordField.text];


NSData *postData = [dataToServer dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];

[self.serviceURLReq setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[self.serviceURLReq setHTTPBody:postData];

if ([self.userNameField hasText] && [self.passwordField hasText]) {


    self.dataTask = [self.urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:self.serviceURLReq completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

            //1
            AD.serverResponseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

            NSLog(@"server response is %@",AD.serverResponseDict);

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // 2
                LVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];

                [self.navigationController pushViewController:LVC animated:YES]; // 3
            });
        });


    }];


    [self.dataTask resume];

}
```

This is the code that i have written and when i enter wrong details it just showing message like server response is (null)

Comment: If user login creds are invalid, show an alert view saying "You have entered invalid username or password"!

Comment: And how do know the details that , it is correct or incorrect ?

Comment: @ParvendraSingh I don't know how to check whether the details are correct or not. thats what my problem. Im asking the same. how to check whether entered details are correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know when you are getting those erros, so a completion handler would be nice to have in that Login Call. After that, you can simple by JSON error specify if are showing a error, or navigate to another view controller. Here is how you show a error in objective-C:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                                         message:@"Message"
                                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
//We add buttons to the alert controller by creating UIAlertActions:
UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                 handler:nil]; //You can use a block here to handle a press on this button
[alertController addAction:actionOk];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And this is how you navigate to another view controller:

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyBoardName" bundle:nil];
MemberDetailsViewController* controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerIdentiferInStoryBoard"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerName animated:YES];
```

Comment: I know both of them but I dont know how to check whether entered details are correct or not. But anyways Thankyou for your time for posting the answer @ppinho

Comment: After calling the webservice, it should return with an answer, so you need to check the webservice answer and look for a success or insucess, or the term that the developer used to say it's right or wrong. If you post your JSON answer, i can help you, but without knowing the answer it's difficult

Comment: Can you actually provide the result of this: 

NSLog(@"server response is %@",AD.serverResponseDict);


Because it's inside that you need to check if there's a success or failure

Comment: But in order to check if it's success or failure, your response should have a JSON, with multiple fields, in which you can check if it's a success or failure, that null can be multiple things like request not properly made.

Comment: but if i enter correct details its printing the data

Comment: And on that data, you don't have a field that indicates whether it's a success or failure so you can show alert or navigate?

Comment: @saikiran, Please contact with your backend developer, and check your Request and Responce from server side once. Might be the details are missing on server side OR you send a blank details to server.

Comment: I really appreciate both of your work. Thank you so much. I have contacted the backend developer and the issue has been solved. I actually a major problem which i'm trying from a week but i don't know how to explain it in stack overflow. Can any of you provide mail or skypeID if possible

Comment: @ParvendraSingh I have sent you a mail kindly check it

Comment: @saikiran yes i got your email